Forestploter in r : how to customize the colors according to the significance levels in the forest plot
I have a dataset that includes estimates for two groups, Trt 1 and Trt 2. I created a forest plot to visualize these estimates using forestploter package in r.
library(forestploter)

dt <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "example_data.csv", package = "forestploter"))

dt$Subgroup <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), 
                      dt$Subgroup,
                      paste0("   ", dt$Subgroup))

dt$n1 <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Treatment), "", dt$Treatment)
dt$n2 <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), "", dt$Placebo)

dt$`result 1 ` <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
dt$`result 2` <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")

dt$`significance_trt1_result1` <- sample(c("*", "***", "ns"), length(dt$est_gp1), replace = TRUE)
dt$`significance_trt1_result2` <- sample(c("*", "***", "ns"), length(dt$est_gp2), replace = TRUE)
dt$`significance_trt2_result1` <- sample(c("*", "***", "ns"), length(dt$est_gp3), replace = TRUE)
dt$`significance_trt2_result2` <- sample(c("*", "***", "ns"), length(dt$est_gp4), replace = TRUE)

head(dt)
         Subgroup Treatment Placebo      est        low       hi   low_gp1    low_gp2   low_gp3   low_gp4  est_gp1   est_gp2
1    All Patients       781     780 1.869694 0.13245636 3.606932 0.1507971 0.35443249 0.3939730 1.1515801 1.181926 1.5163554
2             Sex        NA      NA       NA         NA       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA       NA        NA
3            Male       535     548 1.449472 0.06834426 2.830600 1.9149515 0.09953409 0.3803214 0.3213258 3.266615 0.8291053
4          Female       246     232 2.275120 0.50768005 4.042560 0.6336414 2.57367694 1.0229365 0.3510777 1.971712 3.9719741
5             Age        NA      NA       NA         NA       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA       NA        NA
6          <65 yr       297     333 1.509242 0.67029394 2.348190 1.7679431 0.57329716 0.8433183 2.1637576 2.447051 1.9990500
   est_gp3  est_gp4   hi_gp1   hi_gp2   hi_gp3   hi_gp4  n1  n2                               result 1 
1 1.612725 1.949433 2.924330 2.919964 3.485182 2.862447 781 780                                        
2       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA                                                
3 1.642294 1.607950 3.996409 1.553593 2.573538 2.228632 535 548                                        
4 1.751471 1.742973 3.965617 5.439582 3.674689 3.249342 246 232                                        
5       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA                                                
6 1.390913 3.136695 3.674451 3.399146 2.346744 4.299211 297 333                                        
                                 result 2 significance_trt1_result1 significance_trt1_result2 significance_trt2_result1
1                                                                 *                        ns                       ***
2                                                                 *                        ns                       ***
3                                                               ***                        ns                         *
4                                                                ns                       ***                        ns
5                                                                 *                        ns                         *
6                                                                 *                         *                        ns
  significance_trt2_result2
1                         *
2                        ns
3                       ***
4                        ns
5                       ***
6                         *



In the dataset, there are four columns indicating significance for each group (Trt 1 and Trt2) and result (result 1 and result 2).

Question:
I would like to color the estimates for each group in the forest plot based on their significance.
Specifically, I want to use green4 and blue4 for significant estimates with *, and lighter shades of green and blue for non-significant estimates "ns". Or is it available for this package to assign a lower alpha for "ns" based on those columns significance_trt1_result1, significance_trt1_result2, significance_trt2_result1, significance_trt2_result2?
